# How can I tell what Linux a docker image is running when I am inside it at a command line?

Tags: linux, docker

I am developing an image processing application in Python and TensorFlow for the [DIUx xView challenge](http://challenge.xviewdataset.org/challenge-description).  Challenge submission requires a Docker image cloned from a Docker image [FROM python](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).  I would like to use OpenCL using SYCL as my backend for TensorFlow.  The instructions for how to build this backend assume [Ubuntu 14.04.05 Headless Server](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/03-30-17-setting-up-tensorflow-with-opencl-using-sycl). I am concerned that the Ubuntu 14.04.05 build instructions will not work on the Linux supplied by Docker, so I need to known what Linux Docker is running for me.  I am on Windows 10 Home Edition and I am running the Docker image on [Docker Toolbox Kitematic (Alpha)](https://docs.docker.com/kitematic/userguide/).  I am at a command prompt inside this image.  How can I tell what variant of Linux is running?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/11008/how-do-i-find-out-what-version-of-linux-im-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I tell what variant of Linux is running?

I assume what you want to find out which GNU/Linux distribution is running?

What you want then is either eg.

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

which outputs for instance

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="8"
VERSION="8 (jessie)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

or

```
lsb_release -a
```

which outputs for instance

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 8.10 (jessie)
Release:        8.10
Codename:       jessie
```

The `lsb_release` command might not be available out of the box and would thus need to be installed first (eg. `apt-get install lsb-release`).

Comment: Thanks, that worked and I got the exact same thing you did!

Comment: Great! Happy to hear it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this command inside of the container:

```
cat /etc/issue
```

Or you can do it also from host:

```
docker run --rm python cat /etc/issue
```

It will be "Debian GNU/Linux 9" if the python image is from the Docker Hub.

Or you can try this command if that image is based on Centos, RHEL or Fedora:

```
cat /etc/redhat-release
```

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to the exact question as you formulated it, but you could always find the Dockerfile at dockerhub to find out how it was made:
https://hub.docker.com/_/python/